# How to know when a response from the server has been received?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-webview

Ok, what I want is to ask to my server for an url, and load that url on a `WebView`, but a problem appears: when you run a http request you need to do it in a separate thread, and  `loadUrl()` needs to be runned in the UI thread. So, how can I do to first make the request and then load the url?

The code isn't inside an Activity, so I can't call `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`.

How can I do it?

EDIT: As Alécio suggested, it's better to not have too much code inside custom views, so what I want to do is to create a method that allows me to pass the url when the app has received the response from the server. The code that I'm using for the request is:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://requesturl.com");
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
    String url = getStringFromInputStream(content);
    //web.loadUrl(url);     
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So, it's possible to know when a response has been received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView is a UI component it must be in the context of an Activity or Fragment, so loadUrl() from the UI thread is OK.

If you want to make a server call, process the response before displaying something on the UI, then you might just use the conventional options to connect to a server URL using the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). See the sample code below:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
 readStream(in);
finally {
 urlConnection.disconnect();
}
}
```

In this example, you really need to execute it in a background Thread. Never from the UI Thread.

Comment: when I say that the code isn't inside an activity, it's beacuse it's inside a view, that is inside the content of the activity. Also, I have a reference to the context when I initialize the view.

Comment: With that example I think that I will have the same problem, if am running the code in background, I can't call the loadUrl() to load the response of the server in the webview.

Comment: For such operations, usually you have an Activity that uses an AsyncTask on the onCreate() that calls the server on the method doInBackground() and processes the result on the onPostExecute() where you do set the data fetched from the server into a view component. But if you can just load a Web page into the WebView, you just need to call the webview.loadUrl() directly from the Activity.

Comment: Views are just dummy objects, they just display whatever someone put into them. Don't add to much control inside them, so make sure you make the server call from something else other than inside a custom view.

Comment: Ok, so maybe what I have to ask is "How can I know when a response has been received?", with that I can create a method on my activity and pass the url to the view, avoiding the request inside the custom view

Comment: Have a look at the AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) see the example that is there...from the example, basically you return the  content you downloaded from the server instead of 'Long'..for instance, type String..then on the onPostExecute(String result) you will take the 'result' parameter and set to the View. 'onPostExecute' runs on UI Thread...while the doInBackground() doesn't.

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks, I will implement it! So, finally I wasn't asking the right question.